# Is there an equivalent for keyboardType props with redux-form?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form

I'm getting started with react native and redux form.

I would like to change the keyboardType when filling in my reduxform fields, however the keyboardType props doesn't work:

```
  <Field
      name="email"
      component={textAccount}
      fieldName="Email"
      keyboardType="email-address"
  />
```

Here is the textAccount code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

function textAccount(props) {
  const { input, fieldName } = props;
  return (
    <View>
      <Input
        onChangeText={input.onChange}
        value={input.value}
        placeholder={fieldName}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default textAccount;
```

I'm assuming it's specific to the react native TextInput element, [according to the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#keyboardtype).

In this case, I'd like to be able to display the most accurate keyboard type depending on the field I'm requiring ("email-address" in my example).

Do you know if there is any equivalent props available to be used with "Field"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just put it to the `Input` component:

```
  <Input
    onChangeText={input.onChange}
    value={input.value}
    placeholder={fieldName}
    keyboardType="email-address"
  />
```

Also, looking into `redux-form` code, it seems that all unknown parameters are passed down to the `component`:

```
function textAccount(props) {
  const { input, fieldName, ...rest } = props;
  return (
    <View>
      <Input
        onChangeText={input.onChange}
        value={input.value}
        placeholder={fieldName}
        {...rest}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

and then you should be able to just set `keyboardType` on your `Field`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't understand how I could just set keyboardType directly on my field as it's usually not working?

Comment: @Flora As I said, you *have* to set it on `Input`. However, `Field` passes everything it doesn't know to the `component`, that is, to `textAccount`. You are already using that to pass `fieldName`. You can use the same process to pass `keyboardType` from `Field` to `textAccount`. You only need to write `textAccount` properly and pass every unknown property down to `Input`, as I have demonstrated with `...rest` syntax.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your clarification, everything is working now!

Answer (score 0):

give it a try with `type`

```
 type="email"
```

**Update :**

You need to change it in `Input` instead of `Field`

```
<Input
     keyboardType="email-address"
    ... />
```

Comment: Thanks, but my keyboard has not changed from the "basic" one that is usually displayed...

Comment: Done, just added it to the initial post

Comment: Just tried and it looks great! The issue is that I have several different `Field` (email, password, username and so on) using the same `textAccount` component. Do you have any advice on how you would separate them so I can indeed use the `keyboardType` props according to my needs?

Comment: just same as you are doing with  `input, fieldName`, by passing it  in props

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way :

```
const renderField = ({ label, requiredMarker, keyboardType, placeholder, input: { onChange, ...restInput }}) => {
    return (
    <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '600'}}>{label}<Text style={{color: '#dc3545'}}>{requiredMarker}</Text></Text>
        <TextInput style={{ padding: 5 }} keyboardType={keyboardType} onChangeText={onChange} {...restInput} placeholder={placeholder} autoCapitalize='none'>
        </TextInput>
    </View>);
};

const UserComponent = props => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', margin: 20, justifyContent: 'flex-start', }}>
            <Field name="email" keyboardType="email-address" label="Email: " requiredMarker="*" placeholder="Enter email"
                component={renderField}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Hope it will help!!